# Изображение css в левую сторону

Tags: изображения, css

Что нужно дописать, чтобы изображение было в левой части?
Дополнительную строчку нужно. (Не говорить, что 0 0 уже стоит, дополнительную строчку!)

```
a.rollover {
    background: url('lglogo1.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 89px;
    height: 29px; 
    padding: 0px;
}
a.rollover:hover {
    background: url('lglogo2.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Что-то вроде `<p align="left"></p>`

Вобщем я попробовал сделать по-своему и переместил бекграунд влево - так:

```
a.rollover {
    background: url('lglogo1.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 89px;
    height: 29px; 
    padding-left: 176px;
}
```

Но теперь я столкнулся с такой проблемой: из-за `padding-left: 176px;` справа от бекграундового изображения образовалось много кликабельного пространства как продолжение картинки-ссылки. Как это можно исправить?

Все! Вопрос закрыт. Сам разобрался. Дело было в `margin-right: 176px;`

Answer (score 2):

```
background: url('lglogo1.png') left center no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ох... Не думаю, что если плодить темы, то ответ из ниоткуда появится. Поймите, что у вас не "изображения", как такового. У вас есть изображение в качестве бекграунда. Поэтому, если позиционирование бекграунда вам не подходит, то надо производить какие-то действия с блоком, в котором этот бекграунд расположен. Если надо, чтоб текст "обтекал" этот блок с правой стороны, то попробуйте **float: left;**, т.е. так:

```
a.rollover {
    float: left;
    background: url('lglogo1.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 89px;
    height: 29px; 
    padding: 0px;
}
```